# How to check if a set is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am struggling in finding a way to check if a set is compact. I know by definition that the set is compact if it is closed and bounded, but what about practice?

Especially if I have something like that:

$$\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2 < 2\}$$

Do you know how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. That specific set is not compact since it is not a closed set: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{2}-\frac1n,0\right)=(\sqrt{2},0)$, which does not belong to your set, whereas each $\left(\sqrt{2}-\frac1n,0\right)$ does.

Comment: Thank you Josè, in general how could I approach the problem?

Comment: In general (in the context of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$), you check whether or not your set is closed and whether or not your set is bounded.

Comment: Thank you, I will post another question for another kind of problem about the same topic later. Thank you so much

Comment: If you do that, then I suggest that you keep in mind that what you wrote about compact sets (that they are, by definition, the sets which are closed and bounded) is how compact sets are usually introduced in Real Analysis courses (when we are dealing with subsets of $\mathbb R^n$), but it is *not* the general definition of compact set.